# Why mysql full text search is still slow with multiple where conditions?

Tags: mysql, performance, search, full-text-search

I have below queries:

It searches from table with around 800k records.

```
SELECT id FROM news_article
    WHERE cat_id=1 AND source_id=7
      AND crawl_date>1624947312
      AND crawl_date<1624949312
    ORDER BY score DESC,id ASC;
```

-> 0.05s, with 100 rows

```
SELECT id,MATCH(title) AGAINST('test query') as score
    FROM news_article
    WHERE cat_id=1 AND source_id=7
      AND crawl_date>1624947312
      AND crawl_date<1624949312
      AND MATCH(title) AGAINST('test query')
    ORDER BY score DESC,id ASC LIMIT 0,1;
```

-> It took up to 5-6s

I got index on `(cat_id, source_id, crawl_date)`

I wonder why using full text search in this case is still that slow? As i understand it only perform full text search in 100 rows only, not from 800k table record because of using multiple where conditions?

Anyway to speed it up?

Comment: Did you try to add an index to the columns?

Comment: @mfort i have index on all required columns

Comment: Does this help?  `INDEX(cat_id, source_id, crawl_date)`

Comment: @RickJames I already had that index, but it doesn't speed up anything. The trouble is the full text search condition seems not to find on `crawl_date` range, it scans whole table to find

Comment: @TomSawyer - I suggest you file a bug report with bugs.mysql.com .